# Spring Authentication interface get User Id

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Is there a way to get the user id from the Authentication interface? I am only able to get only the username.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/photo/" , method = RequestMethod.POST,headers = {"content-type=multipart/form-data"})
public @ResponseBody Photo addPhotoData(@RequestParam("data") MultipartFile photoData, Authentication authentication) {
    authentication.getName();
    Photo p = photoService.save(photoData,authentication);
    return p;
}
```

Security conf:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

private final UserService userDetailsService;
private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

public SecurityConfiguration(UserService userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .cors().and()
    .csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SecurityConstants.SIGN_UP_URL)
    .permitAll()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, SecurityConstants.VERIFICATION_EMAIL_URL)
    .permitAll()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SecurityConstants.PASSWORD_RESET_REQUEST_URL)
    .permitAll()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SecurityConstants.PASSWORD_RESET_URL)
    .permitAll()
    .antMatchers(SecurityConstants.H2_CONSOLE)
    .permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/**", "/swagger*/**", "/webjars/**")
    .permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
    .addFilter(getAuthenticationFilter())
    .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
    .sessionManagement()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}

protected AuthenticationFilter getAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
    final AuthenticationFilter filter = new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager());
    filter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/user/login");
    return filter;
}

@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource()
{
    final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
       
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE","OPTIONS"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
    
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    
    return source;
}
  }
```

User service:

```
public interface UserService extends UserDetailsService{
User createUser(User user);
User getUser(String email);
User getUserByUserId(String customerId);
    }
```

User service impl:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
Utils utils;

@Autowired
BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

/*@Autowired
PasswordResetTokenRepository passwordResetTokenRepository;*/

@Override
public User createUser(User user) {

    if (userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail()) != null)
        throw new UserServiceException("Record already exists");


    String publicUserId = utils.generateUserId(30);
    user.setCustomerId(publicUserId);
    user.setEncryptedPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    //userEntity.setEmailVerificationToken(utils.generateEmailVerificationToken(publicUserId));
    User userSaved = userRepository.save(user);

    return userSaved;
}

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);

    if (user == null)
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(email);

    /*return new User(customer.getEmail(), customer.getEncryptedPassword(),
            customer.getEmailVerificationStatus(),
            true, true,
            true, new ArrayList<>());*/

    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(), user.getEncryptedPassword(), new ArrayList<>());
}

@Override
public User getUser(String email) {
    User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);

    if (user == null)
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(email);

    return user;
}

@Override
public User getUserByUserId(String customerId) {

    User user = userRepository.findByCustomerId(customerId);

    if (user == null)
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User with ID: " + customerId + " not found");

    return user;
    }
```

CustomeSecurityUser:

```
 public class CustomSecurityUser extends User implements UserDetails {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = -4381938875186527688L;

 public CustomSecurityUser() {}

 public CustomSecurityUser(User user) {
   //this.setAuthorities(user.getAuthorities());
   this.setId(user.getId());
   this.setPassword(user.getPassword());
   //this.setUsername(user.getUsername());
  }

 @Override
 public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
   return null;
 }

 @Override
 public String getUsername() {
   return null;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
   return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
   return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
   return true;
 }

 @Override
  public boolean isEnabled() {
   return true;
 }
}
```

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai can you be more specific?

Comment: Can you add security config class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as well as any UserDetailsService class to see how the principal is populated?

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai sure I have added it

Comment: Currently you don't have user id in authentication because you are returning, `return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(), user.getEncryptedPassword(), new ArrayList<>());`. It only has email.

Comment: what should I return to be correct? the User from security or my customsecurityuser?

Comment: See my answer here, how to return a new type of object https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62662036/how-do-i-configure-preauthorize-to-recognize-the-id-of-my-logged-in-user/62717000#62717000. Happy to get help if you get stuck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217691/discussion-between-kavithakaran-kanapathippillai-and-stefano-maglione).